# Accepting alphanumeric and 1 dot only in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, codeigniter

I am creating an app using CodeIgniter (back-end) and AngularJS (front-end).
How can I validate user input in AngularJs that only allows characters from a-z-A-Z, numbers and 1 dot (anywhere as long as not in the end of the string)?

`/[^A-Za-z0-9\.]/` is that enough?

BTW, my code structure is inspired with this simple example from AngularJS docs. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D

```
UPDATE:

1 dot must not be the first/last character of the string and it must be optional.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood: you want to check that the string is made of only alphanumeric characters and maximum one dot, not located at the end nor the beginning of the string.

You can use (see [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/iK6oL4/2)):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$
```

**Explanation**

- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`: match all the leading alphanumeric characters (at least one)
- `(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?`: optional non-capturing group - we match a unique dot, followed by  minimum one alphanum
- `^$`: anchors matching the beginning and end of string, making sure the string is composed *only* of what we want